# Production Environment for Spring Cloud Config using Git/Vault

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

Spring Boot -  2.0.0.M3
Spring cloud - Finchley.M1

I want to know if someone is using Spring Cloud config server with both vault and git support in a production setup using Database storage backend.
I have evaluated Spring cloud config using vault and contemplating whether to go for Oracle JCE to encrypt username/pwd or Vault and seek suggestions on the same. we are working on Springboot/microservices.

Following are my findings -

1. Vault will introduce an additional layer and thus will introduce additional usecases of  security, auditing while communicating with Vault.
2. Spring cloud Config actuator endpoints are broken for the milestone release at this point for generation of encrypted values and /encrypt /decrypt may not work if we go for Oracle JCE support so we generate encrypted values through stable versions.
3. We do not wish to use consul server and are trying to use Cassandra as Storage backend.
4. I used Vault Authentication backend using AppRole and generated a Token (different from root token as it's unsafe to use the same) with read permissions. However, Spring Cloud config at the moment support only Token based authentication from client side. That means we first generate token from Vault and then pass it as commandline/env variable.
   Some additional points of concern are expiry of token (though we can have non-expiry token not sure about pros/cons), restarts, safety issues, instantiating new microservices. There is no provision of dynamic tokens/authentication at cloud config side.
5. For milestone release i found that the client side encryption/decryption is not working as of now using recommended inclusion of RSA jar. Here is the ticket i opened.
   https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/805#issuecomment-332491536

These are some of my observations, please share your thoughts if there is any case study/whitepaper that address spring cloud config vault usecases, setup and challenges for production micro-services environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to me. One think I would state is that the App Role backend utilizes two distinct tokens, and indeed spring-cloud-config-vault does indeed support this functionality, see: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/single/spring-cloud-vault.html#_approle_authentication. I leverage vault in the same way I leverage config server, as per the documentation. I don't encrypt any values in my config, I just don't put them there. I put the secret values in vault and let it serve config. As long as keys don't collide, you don't have to mess with anything, otherwise you may need adjust the priority so vault wins, again see the documentation that I pointed to above. I wouldn't mess with encryption/decryption in spring-cloud-config personally. Because you have to check the keys into SCM or distribute them to your teams for local development, you lose the value of having these keys IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Spring Cloud vault does support but not Spring cloud config with Vault. Only way seems to be passing X-Config-token from Microservice to Config Server. We are bit skeptical with this part of generating tokens manually or through script. Especially with containerization and when new MS instances will be spawn. Not sure about this approach especially in production setup.